# Keycloak - how to disable sharing session between two (Angular) client apps?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, session, keycloak

I have two angular client applications that use Keycloak's angular client for authentication. The problem is, that when i log in on one of them, i'm automatically being logged to another one. I have separate client for each one though.

Keycloak service initialization looks like this in both apps:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule
  ],
  providers: [KeycloakService],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
    this.keycloakService
      .init({config: environment.keycloak, initOptions: {onLoad: 'login-required'}})
      .then(() => app.bootstrap(AppComponent));
  }
}
```

Keycloak config for the first app:

```
const keycloakConfig: KeycloakConfig = {
  realm: 'quick',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/auth',
  clientId: 'quick-ui-customer'
};


export const environment = {
  production: false,
  keycloak: keycloakConfig,
};
```

And for the second one:

```
const keycloakConfig: KeycloakConfig = {
  realm: 'quick',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/auth',
  clientId: 'quick-ui-employee'
};


export const environment = {
  production: false,
  keycloak: keycloakConfig,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a core feature of `Single Sign On` protocol. But if you don't want to share session, then create clients in different realms.

Comment: Thanks, seems that's the way i'll go.

Comment: Or use a realm per javascript-client.